# How to use objects that got the private copy-constructor and assignment-constructor?

Tags: c++, private-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a object whose copy constructor and copy assignment is private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979222/how-to-use-a-object-whose-copy-constructor-and-copy-assignment-is-private)

In reading *TCPL*, I got a problem, as the title refered, and then 'private' class is:

```
class Unique_handle {
private:   
    Unique_handle& operator=(const Unique_handle &rhs);  
    Unique_handle(const Unique_handle &rhs); 
public:
    //...
}
```

The using code is:

```
struct Y {
    Unique_handle obj;
};
```

And I want to do such operations

```
main()
{
    Y y1;
    Y y2 = y1;
    return 0;
}
```

although, these code are come from TCPL, but I still can not got the solution... Can anybody help me, appreciate.

Comment: Why ask a duplicate of your own question?

Answer (score 1):

Evidently you need "friend" declarations in that class, or that class already has static accessors that will create or even assign the instance you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm just a beginner of stackoverflow, but as you suggestion, I have learned the format of question. Thank you again, forgive my poor English,plz...